# Using multiple namespaces

Tags: c++, c++11

"I am brand new to C++, and fairly new to coding in general. I have a few questions regarding namespaces.

What exactly is a namespace, and is it possible to use multiple namespaces in a single source file?

I was also curious about the result of introducing a namespace in different locations in a source file.

I know it is possible to specify a namespace at the beginning of a source file, ie after including the input output stream,

```
using namespace std;
```

or within functions and within lines of code,

```
std::cout << … << std::endl;
```

What is the difference between introducing these two namespaces in these two locations?

Are there other ways to introduce a namespace to a source file?

Comment: Here is a very good [introduction to namespaces](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/namespace-in-c/)

Comment: Have a look through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice).  It also sounds like you could use a [good C++ book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)

Comment: Partial Duplicate: [What exactly is a namespace and why is it necessary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32161199/what-exactly-is-a-namespace-and-why-is-it-necessary)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> What exactly is a namespace, and is it possible to use multiple namespaces in a single source file?

A [namespace](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/namespace) is like a container for variable and function names. When you have a very large project, you might find that more than one part of the project may use the same name for something.

You can use as many namespaces as you'd like in a single source file.

```
int aVariable;

namespace ModuleA
{
    int aVariable;
}

namespace ModuleB
{
    int aVariable;
}
```

None of these declarations of `aVariable` interfere with each other because they are all in different namespaces.

> I was also curious about the result of introducing a namespace in different locations in a source file.

There are different ways to *use* a specific namespace...

```
// Somewhere in your code...
int var = aVariable;              // Uses the global aVariable
int varA = ModuleA::aVariable;    // Uses the ModuleA aVariable
int varB = ModuleB::aVariable;    // Uses the ModuleB aVariable
```

You can also use the `using` keyword to import one or more of the variables or functions from a namespace into the current scope.

```
// Take everything from a namespace
using namespace ModuleA;
// Or take just one thing from a namespace
using ModuleB::aVariable;
```

There is a gotcha with the example I have given so far; `aVariable` can only be declared once in any context, so when you have both a global `aVariable` and use `using namespace ModuleA;` you will end up declaring the `aVariable` name twice in that context! This will show up as a compiler error.

---

One more important thing to know about `using namespace ...`:

If this line is found in a header file, any other file that includes that header will also receive the imported names from that namespace. This can lead to unexpected name collisions between your code and other people's code. It is generally frowned upon to put `using namespace std;` in *any* header file.

I recommend that you use the fully qualified name for a variable or function as much as possible. So use `std::min(a, b)` instead of just `min(a, b)`. Even if you have a `using namespace std;` in your source code the `std::` prefix still works. Eventually when your project gets large enough you may need to remove the `using namespace std;` line and then you won't have to fix hundreds of uses of `std::` functions.

Answer (score 2):

One major difference is that every calls to a free function in a namespace becomes unqualified when using a namespace.

This is useful for enabling [ADL](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/adl) (Argument Dependent Lookup) calls:

```
namespace A {
    struct S {};
    void swap(S&, S&) {
        std::cout << "swapped S" << std::endl;
    }
}

template<typename T>
void adl_swap(T& a, T& b) {
    using namespace std;

    // we don't tell std::, so it's an unqualified call
    // may call function in the namespaces of T
    swap(a, b);
}

int main() {
    int a = 0;
    int b = 0;
    adl_swap(a, b); // calls std::swap

    A::S s1, s2;
    adl_swap(s1, s2); // calls A::swap
}
```

As you can see, the using namespace is inside the function, so it's not used globally, but only inside the function scope.

Also in the function `adl_swap`, we use function inside the `A` namespace. We don't actually name because it is implicit.

Another way to bring namespace symbols is to use symbols individually instead of the whole namespace:

```
using std::cout;

int main() {
    using std::endl;
    cout << "Unqualified names!" << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can have two `using` statements together:

```
using namespace std;
using namespace boost::locale;
```

You can also alias a namespace:

```
namespace po=boost::program_options;
```

Answer (score 1):

The location of the `using` determines the scope it affects. If you do it in a function, then it will only affect code in that function after the `using` statement. If you do it at the top of the file, it will affect everything in the file below it.

As for what it does, it makes it so you don't need to prefix things in that package with the name of the package. So, instead of `std::cout` you would just need `cout`.

It is possible to use multiple namespaces in one file, but I would not recommend it. If you have two things with the same name in different namespaces, and you try to use one of them without specifying the namespace, it will randomly choose one and cause very confusing errors.