# Accessing a global and namespace variable

Tags: c++, namespaces, using-directives

I am trying to access variable x using using directive in the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int x = 10;
namespace e {
int x = 5;
}
int main() {
using namespace e; // Because of this line compiler shows error
cout << x;
return 0;
}
```

In general we use the following line to access x but I am getting error
We can also use **using e::x;**
But my question is why can't we use **using namespace e;**

Comment: Note, the error is not on the line you pointed, but one below. If you have `using namespace e;`, how can compiler distinguish between `::x` and `::e::x`?

Comment: Can u please explain clearly as I am learning this topic for the first time?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why and how should I use namespaces in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4211827/why-and-how-should-i-use-namespaces-in-c)

Comment: These 2 answer may help you out!: [Why and how should I use namespaces in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4211827/why-and-how-should-i-use-namespaces-in-c)   & [What exactly is a namespace and why is it necessary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32161199/what-exactly-is-a-namespace-and-why-is-it-necessary)

Comment: I don't think so

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's start with another example.

```
const int x = 10;

namespace e {
const int y = 5;
}

int main()
{
std::cout << e::y;
using namespace e;
std::cout << y;
}
```

There is variable with value 10 and name `x` in global namespace (which can be referred to as `x` simply) and variable with value 5 with name `y` in namespace `e` (which must be referred to as `e::y`).

By adding `using namespace e;`, you *inject* all names from namespace `e` into global namespace. This means global namespace now contains names `x` and `y`, and namespace `e` contains name `y`. You can now refer to variable with value `5` using both `y` and `e::y`.

Now, back to your example. If we change `y` to `x`:

```
const int x = 10;

namespace e {
const int x = 5;
}

int main()
{
std::cout << e::x;
using namespace e;
std::cout << x;
}
```

There is `x` in global namespace and `x` in namespace `e`. By adding `using namespace e;` you inject all the names from namespace `e` to global namespace, so now global namespace contains names `x` and `x`, and namespace `e` contains name `x`. See the problem? Global namespace contains two names `x`, which confuses the compiler. When you try to print variable under the name `x`, compiler looks up names in global namespace and finds two `x`. It cannot choose which one you meant, so it throws error.

This is the main reason why [`using namespace` (particularly `using namespace std;`) is considered evil](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice). One can easily break working code by updating a library or introducing a new function. Compiler error is best outcome in such a case, but sometimes it's possible that compiler will silently replace one function by another, because it matches better.

You can still access both variables using *fully qualified names*:

```
int main()
{
using namespace e;
std::cout << ::x << " "; //x from global with fully quafilied name
std::cout << ::e::x << " "; //x from namespace e with fully qualified name
std::cout << e::x; //not fully qualified, but not ambiguous either - only one x in namespace e
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In this example it may seem that `using namespace e;` makes names from namespace `e` available in `main` function scope. However it does not do this. Instead it tries to inject names (during unqulified lookup in `main`) from `namespace e` into the nearest enclosing namespace of `main` and `namespace e`, to the global namespace that is. Therefore `x` becomes ambiguous.

Comment: Can you please explain using simple words?

Comment: @BethBorgov `using namespace e;` makes compiler search for name `x` in `main` as if `x` from namespace `e` was declared next to `int x = 10;` in global namespace.